# Assigning data to a multidimensional NumPy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, netcdf

I'm trying to assign data to a Numpy array from a Pandas dataframe. The Numpy array is actually a netCDF variable with a slightly odd structure that I can't modify, to maintain compatibility.

The first dimension is the data (unlimited), while the second dimension is a reference to a given sensor (each sensorProcValue variable might have up to 12 sensors). For each sensor, I need to assign a Pandas Series (from a DataFrame).

My attempt:

```
sensorProcValue[:, current_sensor_index] = cnv.data[cnv_short_name][:]
```

This results in an error, which doesn't surprise me. The following works, but is obviously extremely inefficient:

```
for i in range(0, len(cnv.data[cnv_short_name])):
    sensorProcValue[i, current_sensor_index] = cnv.data[cnv_short_name][i]
```

The shape of the data is as follows:

```
print(np.shape(sensorProcValue))
>>> (0, 12)
print(np.shape(cnv.data[cnv_short_name]))
>>> (40828,)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here (I'm still getting my head around Pandas/NumPy data structures), so any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: So, `sensorProcValue` is an empty array because it's shaped : `(0,12)`? Also, is `current_sensor_index` a constant?

Comment: Yes, it's empty. current_sensor_index isn't a constant, the code's in a loop that processes each sensor in turn. But in this example, it's 0.

Comment: If it's empty, how could you do the assignment : `sensorProcValue[i, current_sensor_index]`? Doesn't look right to me, unless you are modifying at each iteration.

Comment: Well, it's a netCDF variable - this is where I define it:

`sensorFlag = scanfile.createVariable("sensorFlag", "i1", ("scan", "activeSensor"), fill_value=-53)`